# Como nomear os índices de um array de arrays de acordo com um outro array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tendo o seguinte array de arrays

```
array1=[indice1[1,2,3], indice2[4,5,6]]
```

e o segundo

```
array2=['nome1','nome2']
```

Como fazer com que o primeiro array (array de arrays = array1) tenha os mesmos nomes em seus índices do segundo array?

Dessa forma:

```
print(array1)


[nome1[1,2,3], nome2[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: tem algo errado com essa sintaxe em array1=[indice1[1,2,3], indice2[4,5,6]]

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível "nomear" listas pois elas trabalham apenas com posições. O que você talvez esteja procurando se chama [dicionário](http://excript.com/python/funcoes-dicionarios.html), que é um objeto no qual possui uma chave e um valor.

Utilizando dicionários, você pode definir um "nome" (chave) para suas listas (valor) e obter cada valor através de suas respectivas chaves. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
dicionario = {"indice1": [1, 2, 3], "indice2": [4, 5, 6]}

dicionario["indice1"] # Retorna: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: E se eu tiver um dicionário assim:

```dados = {"indice1": [1, 2, 3], "indice2": [4, 5, 6]}```

e quiser nomear os índices com o seguinte array:

```names= ['nome1', 'nome2']```

eu posso fazer assim:

```dados.keys()=names```

???

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, o `keys()` não é um atributo e sim um método, logo não é possível fazer essa sintaxe que você deseja. Agora, o que você quer dizer com nomear os índices com um array ?

Comment: Se o que você está querendo dizer é transformar uma lista em uma chave, não, isso não é possível pois os únicos valores que você pode usar como chaves são tipos primitivos (string, int, float, bool).

Comment: Se você quer transformar os elementos dentro da lista `names` em chaves, sim é possível e você pode fazê-lo percorrendo a lista com um `for` loop e sempre adicionando um valor à chave, dessa forma: `for name in names: dic[name] = None`.